# Aggregate and Group By in Apache Phoenix

Tags: mysql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to execute a query in Apache Phoenix where i am using aggregate and groupby function. I have executed the same query in mysql and it works but in Phoenix I tried the query based on mysql query but it failed. Please see mysql query and Phoenix query below.

**MySQL:**

```
select id3, id4, name, descr, status, min(date) from table1
where status = "inactive" group by id3, id4, name, descr, status
```

**Result:**
id3     id4             name    descr   status     min(date)

17773   8001300701101   name1   descr1  INACTIVE    20121202
17785   9100000161822   name3   descr3  INACTIVE    20121201

**Phoenix Query:**

There is no difference in the query between MySQL and Phoenix.

```
select id3, id4, name, descr, status, min ( date )  from table1
WHERE status = 'inactive' group by  id3, id4, name, descr, status;
```

But i am getting the below error Can any one explain please?

```
Error: ERROR 1018 (42Y27): Aggregate may not contain columns not in GROUP BY. ELS_NAME (state=42Y27,code=1018)
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 1018 (42Y27): Aggregate may not contain columns not in GROUP BY. ELS_NAME
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:361)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:133)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ExpressionCompiler.throwNonAggExpressionInAggException(ExpressionCompiler.java:1141)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ProjectionCompiler.compile(ProjectionCompiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleFlatQuery(QueryCompiler.java:490)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleQuery(QueryCompiler.java:447)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:154)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:331)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:314)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:230)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:226)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:225)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1066)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292
```

Comment: why name it name, maybe backtick it, try not to use reserved words in case that is remotely related

Comment: @Drew Pierce sure I will take and update the column name in the table. My issue remains even I use a different column name

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check into column naming.

> All table, column family and column names are uppercased unless they are double quoted in which case they are case sensitive.

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html

Comment: Also, before you execute aggregation query, why not run a simple select to project all columns into the result set. This way you can clarify that column names are valid.